# Node JS Express Thread clarification

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am relatively new to node js, and have read some of the texts of its architecture.

I understand about about the event loop, the main thread(V8 engine thread) and the rest as `libuv` threads. As soon as a main thread needs to do async processing it hands it over to `libuv` threads, and in return they add the result in event loop.

My concern is over `express`. So who is inserting the http requests into the event loop. Is there a separate dedicated thread for it or is it one of the `libuv` thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually,`express` is just use the nodejs's http API. Whatever it is `express` or `hapi` or some other nodejs's framework,they just use the nodejs's http/https api as basis. And the concept of event loop does not come from nodejs, that is originated from javascript, js use that to handle async function and so does nodejs.Then for the http request, that's same with other async function, the V8 entrust the request to nodejs's relative module and in turn be entrusted to the OS, when the response is received or a http request is received on the port and thereby to the the V8 thread, the V8 pushes a callback into queue and wait to be invoke after the sysn thread.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, not sure about this part "wait to be invoke after the sysn thread". You meant the main(sync) thread?

Comment: Js or NodeJs is single thread langulage.So I think that is no concept about main thread or others, the async thread is not handle by js interpreter(V8 engine).The v8 just accept a callback.

Comment: Apologies, By asynchronous threads I meant threads of `libuv`. By main thread I meant V8 event loop thread. I need to understand that `libuv` does come in picture right. The OS will probably not add the callback in V8 event loop, and the asynchronous thread of `libuv` will listen to the OS notification of a request being received and thereby adding the event in V8 event loop.

Comment: Edited the question also.

Comment: Depend on your comment, I mean the main theard,which offer by v8